# Network lags when form resize

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking

**Premise**
I have simple networking prototype.
It has gui form and background thread (I call it *data thread*) to read incoming data. *Data thread* monitors available data in `socket` and reads data.
Data transmitted from client in packets with length 1040 bytes with approximate rate 50 messages per second.

**Regular**
When program works, number of available bytes in socket is equal to data what thread reads and equal to data package size. In log I see something like this: <kbd>available:1040, read:1040</kbd>.

**Trouble**
But when I start to resize gui form, data thread cannot process incoming data in time. And in that time I see <kbd>available:2080, read:2082</kbd> or even <kbd>available:5200, read:5200</kbd>. I suppose that during form rendering process socket get several messages from network.

**Even worse** 
Later I plan to parse incoming data and render it in gui. I foresee that this operations will require more cpu resources and networking process will lag even more.

**Question**
What can I do to reduce network lag?

**Ideas**

- play with thread priorities.
- stop update layout while form resize:
  this.ResizeBegin += (s, e) => { this.SuspendLayout(); };
  this.ResizeEnd += (s, e) => { this.ResumeLayout(true); };
- data rate is too high, all in vain.

**Some code**
*Data thread* code:

```
void readDataRunner()  
{  
  log("readdata thread started");  
  while (!bStopReadDataThread)  
  {  
    if (client != null)  
    {  
      int bytesAvailable = 0;  
      bytesAvailable = client.Client.Available;  

      if (bytesAvailable > 0)  
      {  
        //create buffer and read data from socket
        byte[] bt = new byte[bytesAvailable];  
        int readed = client.Client.Receive(bt);  

        //extract header from message
        NetMessage header = new NetMessage();  
        header.setDefaultValues();  
        byte[] b = new byte[16];  
        Array.Copy(bt, b, 16);  
        header = tools.fromBytes(b);  

        //debug message
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("available:" + bytesAvailable + "\tread:" + readed);  
      }  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Post relevant code. Why does rendering matters to `Socket` or even worker thread? am confused.

Comment: Are you doing anything other than reading data from your socket in your worker thread?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when `readDataRunner` is not running in its own thread, but  instead is in the UI thread. Move it to a separate thread and your issue should disappear.

Things you can use: `Thread`, `Task`, `BackgroundWorker`.

Drop your ideas altogether, here is why

- play with thread priorities (this won't matter if your UI thread is busy with non-UI stuff)
- stop update layout while form resize (won't solve your problem as it is not relevant here)
- data rate is too high, all in vain (it's not, you should only get concerned when you see CPU and network traffic constantly peaking at 100%)

Comment: "It has gui form and background thread (I call it data thread) to read incoming data". `readDataRunner` already runs in separated thread(*data thread*).